# vbscript to find number of tables present in word document

Tags: vbscript

```
Sub inserttable()

Dim wdapp
Dim wddoc
Dim strdocname
Set wdapp = CreateObject("word.application")
wdapp.Visible = True
Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\dssuser.GGNS1DSS22\Desktop\sahil3.doc")
table = wddoc.table.Count
If table = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("no table found")
Else
    MsgBox ("table found")
    Exit Sub
End If
wddoc.Close
wdapp.Quit

Set wddoc = Nothing
Set wdapp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a explanation about your problem! Also please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are so close! If you didn't have a typo in your code, then this is it (**Tables**, not *table*):

```
table = wddoc.tables.Count
```